# Failing to execute the first conditional after asking a question

Tags: bash, scripting

so I'm trying to build one of my first scripts, but it doesn't execute correctly.

I would like to `git fetch --prune origin` inside the script, but before that, I would like to ask the question, would you like to "continue"  or "exit". The "exit" part works, but not the "continue" part.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Ready to git-some and sync your local branches to the remote counterparts ?"

REPLY= read -r -p 'Continue? (type "c" to continue), or Exit? (type "e" to exit): '

if [[ "${REPLY}" == 'c ' ]]
then
  echo "About to fetch"
  git fetch --prune origin
elif [[ "${REPLY}" == 'e' ]]
then
  echo "Stopping the script"
fi
```

Comment: «The "exit" part works, but not the "continue" part.»  Does it say `Stopping the script`, or does it just silently exit?  What happens if you type a letter other than “c” or “e”?  What debugging have you done?  (Hint: printing variables is a good idea 107% of the time.)

Comment: @G-Man it was saying the "Stopping the script". Had not done any debugging, but (mind blowing) just realised that I could actually do `print MY_VAR_NAME` thanks for that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have space in first if condition `'c '`:

```
if [[ "${REPLY}" == 'c ' ]]
```

The condition looks for `c[space]` or `e`

Remove it.

```
if [[ "${REPLY}" == 'c' ]]
```

Use `else` condition to debug as below:

```
if [[ "${REPLY}" == 'c' ]]
then
    echo "About to fetch"
    git fetch --prune origin
elif [[ "${REPLY}" == 'e' ]]
then
    echo "Stopping the script"
else
    echo "${REPLY} is INVALID"
fi
```

I prefer to use a switch case for this kind of scenario:

```
echo "Ready to git-some and sync your local branches to the remote counterparts ?"

read -r -p 'Continue? (type "c" to continue), or Exit? (type "e" to exit): ' REPLY

case $REPLY in
    [Cc])
        echo "About to fetch"
        git fetch --prune origin
        ;;
    [Ee])
        echo "Stopping the script"
        exit 1;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid input"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: thanks this works perfectly, and thanks for introducing me to the case statement in bash. :) Question, what  is this [Cc] and [Ee] why the capital letters before?

Comment: to validate both the cases, user can pass arg as `C` or `c`. you can remove the upper case if you dont require.

Comment: `case` uses the same kind of patterns like filename globs. So you could also use say `[Cc]*` to accept any trailing garbage, if you so wish.

Comment: thanks folks !!! Will try to create another script now ;)

Comment: One more question folks, let say I would like to add emojis to my script. Right now I have something like this, but maybe the interpolation is not working correctly?

`UNICORN= '\U1F984\n' FIRE='0xF0 0x9F 0x94 0xA5' echo "${UNICORN} ${FIRE} Ready to git-some and sync your local branches to the remote counterparts ?"`

Comment: @SivaPrasath  just did :)