# Problems escaping a variable when using echo

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to escape the following code with the `echo` command but I keep getting the actual octet and not the emoji.

Also where could I find the octet values of the emojis? I seem to always find the `UTF-8` values.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

UNICORN='\360\237\246\204\n'
FIRE=''

# this does not work when I run the script
printf '\360\237\246\204\n'
printf "Riding a ${UNICORN:Q}"  
echo "Riding a ${UNICORN:Q}" #[Fails]: how to extract the actual emoji?
```

**EDIT_1:** Just updating the code after reading comments

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Note: use hexdump -b to get one-bye octal display

UNICORN_UTF8=$'\360\237\246\204'


printf "U1F525\n"|hexdump -b  # [ASK]: How to translate the return value to a valid UTF8 ?

FIRE_UTF8=$'\125\061\106\065\062\065\012'

echo "Riding a ${UNICORN_locale_encoding}"
echo "${UNICORN_UTF8} + ${FIRE_UTF8}"
```

**EDIT_2:** Posting final code. It sort of works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Author:
# Usage:
# Note: use hexdump -b to get one-bye octal display of the emoji (needed for when ≠ computers use ≠ commandLine tools) 
# Ex: printf "U1F525\n"|hexdump -v -e '"\\" 1/1 "%03o"' ; echo 

UNICORN_UTF8=$'\360\237\246\204'
FIRE_UTF8=$'\xF0\x9F\x94\xA5'
LEAVE_SPACE=\^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$\

echo "Riding an ${UNICORN_UTF8} ${LEAVE_SPACE} out of a ${FIRE_UTF8} ${LEAVE_SPACE} house."
```

Comment: Welcome to this site! Any reason why you don't want to use `printf`? Also see this relevant question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: This is a follow-on question to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466961/ .

Comment: `\octet` and even `\n` are `printf` syntax. what makes you expect `echo` knos ho to interpret them?

Comment: @Philippos thanks, I thought  that `printf` and `echo` behaved the same. New to this `bash` and scripting. 

@MrShunz, main reason is because I would like to use it on an script, and my current scripts has `echo "Ready to git-some and sync your local branches to the remote counterparts ?"`

Comment: @JdeBP correct that is the follow up question to actually all my questions here. I'm trying to incorporate emojis into my [script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466929/failing-to-execute-the-first-conditional-after-asking-a-question)

Comment: `printf U1F525` outputs `U1F525`, 0125 is the code for U. With bash-4.2+ use `printf '\U1F525'` as already shown in answers to both your questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`echo`'s syntax is different from the standard C escapes as supported by `printf`/`awk`/`$'...'`...

In standard `echo` syntax, you need a leading `0` in front of the octal sequence (which can have from 1 to 3 digits)¹:

```
echo '\0360\0237\0246\0204'
```

Note that for `bash`'s `echo` builtin to work with that, you need to enable the `xpg_echo` option²:

```
$ UNICORN_utf8_printf_format='\360\237\246\204'
$ UNICORN_utf8_echo='\0360\0237\0246\0204'
$ UNICORN_utf8=$'\360\237\246\204'
$ printf "$UNICORN_utf8_printf_format\n"

$ printf '%s\n' "$UNICORN_utf8"

$ shopt -s xpg_echo
$ echo "$UNICORN_utf8_echo"
```

Above, only `$UNICORN_utf8` contains a  character, encoded in UTF8. The other ones contain sequences of backslash and digits that are meant to be expanded by the respective tools.

The `%b` format of the `printf` utility also understands the same sequences as `echo`. `%b` was actually added so we can get rid of `echo` which is [impossible to use portably and reliably](/q/65803).

```
$ printf '%b\n' "$UNICORN_utf8_echo"
```

See also (in `zsh` and `bash`³):

```
UNICORN_locale_encoding=$'\U1f984'
```

Which gets you a Unicorn encoded in the locale's encoding, which would make it work even if the locale's encoding was not UTF-8 and also had that character (probably only GB18030, where  is encoded as `$'\225\60\330\66'` and where `$'\360\237\246\204'` would be the encoding of `馃` (`\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-9983}\N{<private use area-E6E9>}`)).

Some `printf` implementations (including GNU `printf` and the `printf` builtin of `zsh`, `ksh93` and recent versions of `bash` (4.2 or above)) also support  those `\UXXXXXXXX` escape sequences in their format argument (or arguments to `%b` except with ksh93); the GNU one needs 8 digits.

---

<sup>¹ GNU coreutils `echo` and busybox `echo` support `\ooo` with `-e` as an extension (not when `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment for GNU `echo`)</sup>

<sup>² other option would be to use the non-standard `-e` option, but then it wouldn't work when both the `posix` and `xpg_echo` options are enabled, like when `bash` is in UNIX compliance mode.</sup>

<sup>³ ksh93 and mksh also support that syntax, but encode in UTF-8 regardless of the locale's encoding; in current (2018) versions of FreeBSD `sh`, you need `\U0001f984` and it only works in UTF-8 locales.</sup>

Comment: Most complete answer! Much appreciated, glad to see this!

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo $'\360\237\230\200\012'
```

(that's `bash`'s `echo`, GNU bash, version 4.3.43(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu))

Or you can use the `echo` binary:

```
$ /usr/bin/echo -e "\360\237\230\200\012"
```

How did I get it? I used maulinglawns's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467249/306023) above to see the emoji's octal:

```
$ printf "\U1F600\n"

$ printf "\U1F600\n"|hexdump -b
0000000 360 237 230 200 012                                            
0000005
```

`hexdump`:
`-b, --one-byte-octal      one-byte octal display`

**EDIT:** If you wanted the unicorn emoji:

```
$ echo $'\360\237\246\204'

$ `which echo` -e '\360\237\246\204'
```

If you want some generic way of getting the octal in that format:

```
printf "\U1F600\n"|hexdump -v -e '"\\" 1/1 "%03o"' ; echo
\360\237\230\200\012
```

The output includes the `\n` as `\012`. The ";echo" will add a newline at the end, it's useful for when trying it on command line, else the shell prompt will be shown right after the output.

Comment: thanks for that function `hexdump -b` :)